# MySQL has gone away with pymysql

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

I am running a query using pymysql in python 3, something like:

```
conn = 'con info here'

cur = conn.cursor()

cu.execute('sql goes here')
```

The query goes among the lines of:

```
load data
local infile 'file path'
ignore into table table_name
fields terminated by '/t'
optionally enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\r\n'
ignore 1 lines

(@col1,
@col2,
@col3)
set
(col1indb = @col1,
col2indb = @col2,
col3indb = @col3)
```

When I execute the query, I immediately get this:

```
File "/opt/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 296, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/opt/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 781, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "/opt/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 942, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "/opt/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1143, in read
    self._read_load_local_packet(first_packet)
  File "/opt/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1178, in _read_load_local_packet
    sender.send_data()
  File "/opt/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1317, in send_data
    self.connection._write_bytes(packet)
  File "/opt/python3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 929, in _write_bytes
    raise err.OperationalError(2006, "MySQL server has gone away (%r)" % (e,))
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2006, "MySQL server has gone away (BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe'))")
```

Since the error occurs immediately, I am sure it is not a timeout. Every single other query that I run works fine, even similar load queries.

My question is, what in the MySQL syntax can cause this error??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with pymysql, python3.5 and remote MySQL server. When I try to insert an entry with a huge LONGTEXT fields (man gcc 4 times, for example) it will answer the same error: `MySQL server has gone away (BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe'))`. It works well when I use just a short text line, something like "HELLO WORLD".

Comment: I got an answer for my case: I had to modify `max_allowed_packet`, so now it can accept bigger sql query.